# How to detect whether a youtube video includes paid promotion via v3 API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We can set the Paid promotion (Paid product placements, sponsorships, endorsements) property on youtube videos, but this property is not appeared in API Document.

Is there any way to detect whether a video includes paid promotion by API?

About paid promotion (Paid product placements, sponsorships, endorsements)
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/154235

Youtube API Document (Videos)
https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no method for that will tell you if a video has any paid promotion part of it.

You may want to consider submitting a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600%2B)